# What can be the reasons of having an UnpicklingError while running pos_tag() from NLTK Python module?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I am currently working on extraction of verbs from text.

I tried to use the example from NLTK documentation, and wrote this:

```
import nltk

snt = 'The rezults are demonstrated below. This is what our experiment 
revealed.'

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(snt)

tagged_words = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
```

Surprisingly, this won't work, and I get an UnpicklingError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "verbs_parser_for_wos.py", line 14, in <module>
    tagged_words = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
 File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\__init__.py", 
 line 161, in pos_tag
    tagger = _get_tagger(lang)
 File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\__init__.py", 
 line 107, in _get_tagger
    tagger = PerceptronTagger()
 File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site- packages\nltk\tag\
 perceptron.py", line 146, in __init__
    self.load(AP_MODEL_LOC)
 File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\
 perceptron.py", line 226, in load
    self.model.weights, self.tagdict, self.classes = load(loc)
 File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py",
 line 875, in load
    resource_val = pickle.load(opened_resource)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. Are you using Python 3.7?

Comment: I tried 3.6 and 3.7, but the rezult is the same for both of them...

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, that all I needed was downloading another package named 'averaged_perception_tagger':

```
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
```